# writeFileSync doesn't callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs, writefile

I am using writeFileSync function to write a file locally, the file does get written, however, the callback function is never called.

I did some googling, some other post are having the issue that it's either 1) passing the content went wrong or 2) having two write function at the same time.

My problem is that there are some other places in my code that is using the writeFileSync, but they are on different routes (not sure if this is the right terminology, localhost:port#/differentroutes <- something like this). I am testing only on my own route so those write functions shouldn't even be called.

Here is my code:

```
if(!fs.existsSync(dir)){
        fs.mkdirSync(dir)
    }

//content is just a string var I swear it's just a string

    fs.writeFileSync('./pages/SubmissionProcess.html',content,function(err){
        if(err){
            throw err
        }else {
            console.log("YES")
        }
    })
```

I never see this "YES" nor error in my console even tho the file is already written....

Comment: Cos it's sync duh, dont need to register a callback!!!!

Comment: @shanks what does that mean...

Comment: You only register callbacks for async functions, sync versions dont need callbacks

Comment: `fs.writeFileSync('./pages/SubmissionProcess.html',content)` should surffice

Comment: @shanks okay...so how do I know it finished???

Comment: you know it finished when execution move to the next after...cos its sync (sequential flow). You may want to surround that with a try catch though for errors

Comment: It is highly recommended that you don't use the `Sync` version unless your program is very basic and does not need to process multiple files where it is waiting for each one to read/write. (It is okay if you processing a single file... for a single purpose... and have no other I/O operations that you might wait on)

Comment: @shanks Thank you ಥ_ಥ

Comment: @CodyG.i disagree..if it's a simple automation script it's fine to use sync, there is no golden rule to that...but if it's on a request "hot path" and you require optimal performance then async versions are much better as they don't block the event loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write file sync doesn't take a callback :D

Take a look at the documentation :

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options

The parameters are (path, data, options)

If you want to check if the file actually wrote, you can read file sync after writing it or check the last time the file was updated. Otherwise, you should try using the async approach.

Answer (score 2):

All of the synchronous methods `throw` rather than passing an error to a callback.

```
try {
    fs.writeFileSync('./pages/SubmissionProcess.html', content);
    console.log('YES');
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
}
```

Comment: Don't think this works, if you put a bad file path like '/' and try it, YES appears still then the error appears after